# How to help WikiLeaks remain up and running?

Tags: security

WikiLeaks is under a lot of attack. It has been ousted from DNS servers, Amazon has kicked it out. It is facing massive DDOS attacks.

Under these circumstances what can WikiLeaks do to remain afloat?

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with webmastering.

Comment: I can understand the comment and closing of this question as it was asked, rather specific to a current event. However, it would be a good question, *very* topical to webmastering if it were rewritten, citing WikiLeaks only as an example, making the technical obstacles more general.

Comment: Agreed with Chris. A collection of knowledge around how to make a web service tolerant to interference from any local jurisdiction would be invaluable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a growing number of issues WikiLeaks are currently dealing with, not only the eviction from Amazon Web Services (http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2010/12/amazon-explains-wikileaks.php), but now their DNS Provider has also decided to no longer provide them with their service (http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2010/12/wikileaks-loses-its-dns-servic.php).

How can you support WikiLeaks?

1. Donate to their cause (https://donations.datacell.com/), providing funding for them to find new providers and continue their work.
2. Show your support for WikiLeaks by not purchasing services from providers who have chosen to drop them (ie Amazon Web Services and EveryDNS).
3. Show your support by purchasing services from providers who have taken on WikiLeaks as a customer, like Bahnhof Web Hosting (http://www.bahnhof.se/colocation.php).
4. Contact your Congressman and urge them to support WikiLeaks in any discussions within the Government. Tell them why you believe WikiLeaks is a force for good, and why it should not be considered a threat to the general public.

Answer (score 0):

They can buy more servers.

I don't think they are going to be shut down anytime soon.